# SQL WHERE tags contain "news"?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Currently, I just started as a developer so i am not sure am I doing it right, I am to develop a website with a blog system. Where each of the record added to the database contains multiple tags to identify it, so I treat them as a string Example: "Gym, School, Backyard". and now I have to count the number of rows inside the database of the blog system, in a condition of the data contains certain tags.
How can I make the SQL request to count it? or is there a simpler way to do this?

> SELECT ID FROM blog WHERE tags Contains 'GYM'?

Comment: SELECT ID FROM blog WHERE tags LIKE '%GYM%'

Comment: Ah that helped. thanks. i completely forgot about that.

Comment: Mind put that in the answer? so i can just finish this post

Comment: Select count(ID) from blog where tag='GYM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like :

SELECT ID FROM blog WHERE tags IN('Gym', 'School', 'Backyard')

for count:

SELECT count(*) FROM blog WHERE tags IN('Gym', 'School', 'Backyard')

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID FROM blog WHERE tags LIKE '%GYM%'
```